# Show content by default on page loading?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Onclick of option, i am getting the data from the database and displaying it below but wanna show it by default on page load.

Comment: If you have no data to compare option values then first option in select will be automatically selected if none other options are selected. If you have data to compare with option value than just add `selected` on the one that matches.

Answer (score 0):

use `selected` attribute for the option you want to be selected on page reload